# Create new column based on characters of one column and condition of another

Tags: r, substring

I have a dataset with 2 columns

```
Filnename                                  Subject
161014_1_A1_B1_1880129006_1801004016_1     A1
161214_1_A1_B1_1861317003_1801206008_1     B1
170202_1_A2_B1_1860415029_1750730086_2     A2
```

I want a third and a fourth column with the Codes of the Participants

```
df$agent <- substr(df, start = 16, stop = 25)
df$partner <- substr(df, start = 27, stop = 36)
```

The problem is I want this to only to happen if there is "A1" or "A2" in the Subject column.

And the opposite should happen if there is "B1" or B2":

```
df$partner <- substr(df, start = 16, stop = 25)
df$agent <- substr(df, start = 27, stop = 36)
```

The result should look like this:

```
Filnename                                  Subject    agent       partner
161014_1_A1_B1_1880129006_1801004016_1     A1         1880129006  1801004016
161214_1_A1_B1_1861317003_1801206008_1     B1         1801206008  1861317003
170202_1_A2_B1_1860415029_1750730086_2     A2         1860415029  1750730086
```

I hope the question is understandable and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(agent = case_when(Subject %in% c("A1", "A2") ~ 
                        substr(Filnename, 16, 25), 
                        TRUE ~ substr(Filnename, 27, 36)), 
          partner = case_when(Subject %in% c("A1", "A2") ~ 
                        substr(Filnename, 27, 36), 
                        TRUE ~ substr(Filnename, 16, 25)))
#                               Filnename Subject      agent    partner
#1 161014_1_A1_B1_1880129006_1801004016_1      A1 1880129006 1801004016
#2 161214_1_A1_B1_1861317003_1801206008_1      B1 1801206008 1861317003
#3 170202_1_A2_B1_1860415029_1750730086_2      A2 1860415029 1750730086
```

---

Or another option would be to rearrange the substring based on the 'Subject' value

```
i1 <- !grepl("A\\d+", df$Subject)
df$new <- df$Filnename
df$new[i1] <-  sub("_(\\d{10})_(\\d{10})", "_\\2_\\1", df$Filnename[i1])
```

and then do an `extract`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   extract(new, into = c("agent", "partner"), ".*_([0-9]{10})_([0-9]{10}).*")
#                               Filnename Subject      agent    partner
#1 161014_1_A1_B1_1880129006_1801004016_1      A1 1880129006 1801004016
#2 161214_1_A1_B1_1861317003_1801206008_1      B1 1801206008 1861317003
#3 170202_1_A2_B1_1860415029_1750730086_2      A2 1860415029 1750730086
```

---

Or using all of the above in the `%>%`

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
 mutate(tmp = ifelse(str_detect(Subject, "A\\d+"), Filnename, 
      str_replace(Filnename, "_(\\d{10})_(\\d{10})", "_\\2_\\1"))) %>% 
 extract(tmp, into = c("agent", "partner"), ".*_([0-9]{10})_([0-9]{10}).*")
#                                Filnename Subject      agent    partner
#1 161014_1_A1_B1_1880129006_1801004016_1      A1 1880129006 1801004016
#2 161214_1_A1_B1_1861317003_1801206008_1      B1 1801206008 1861317003
#3 170202_1_A2_B1_1860415029_1750730086_2      A2 1860415029 1750730086
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Filnename =  c("161014_1_A1_B1_1880129006_1801004016_1", 
 "161214_1_A1_B1_1861317003_1801206008_1", "170202_1_A2_B1_1860415029_1750730086_2"
), Subject = c("A1", "B1", "A2")), .Names = c("Filnename", "Subject"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: With the first option: What do I have to do if didn't make the new columns before your proposed answer (the dataset is as in the beginning of the question)?

Comment: @RenaSo  I updated the 'df' with that command, but then I did copy/paste your original dataset for starting fresh for the second answer

Comment: The first option you mentioned didn't work.  
It says:[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 41 rows ].
Is this the problem?

Comment: @RenaSo  Isn't that a max. print on the screen instead of an error?  Just create an object and check the dimensions i.e. `out <- df %>% mutate(...` and `str(out)`

Comment: I found my mistake. Thank you for your answer. It worked!